# Configure account event auditing with Secedit

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, audit, security

I'm currently putting together a number of PS scripts which can be run against a new webserver in order to harden it prior to it being placed in production. 
One of these scripts will launch secedit and import a policy I have defined. My query is surrounding the  [Event Audit] section of the policy inf file. It contains options for the various aspects to audit against, for instance:

```
[Event Audit]
AuditSystemEvents = 0
AuditLogonEvents = 0
AuditObjectAccess = 0
etc etc
```

From looking at this it would appear that I have two possible values; 1 or 0. My question is how do I set whether to log the Success, Failure or Success & Failure for each event? 
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since played around a bit and found the answer. 
There are 4 possible values for event audits:

- 0 = No auditing
- 1 = Success
- 2 = Failure
- 3 = Success, Failure

I hope this one day provides someone with a quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

The legacy "Event Audit Policy" settings actually have five values (Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232776.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

- `0` = None
- `1` = Success Only
- `2` = Failure Only
- `3` = Success and Failure
- **`4` = None**

*However*, if the `[Registry Values]` section contains this entry;

`MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\SCENoApplyLegacyAuditPolicy 4,1`

A value of `4,1` means that "Advanced Auditing" is in-use (`4`=DWORD,`1`=Enabled), and all of the legacy "Event Audit Policy" settings displayed via `SECedit.exe` will be set to `0`.

The "Advanced Audit Settings" can be queried by running an additional command.

`auditpol.exe /backup /file:C:\AuditPolicy.CSV`